# Does sudo tar alter file permissions or ownership?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, sudo, tar

I'm performing a backup of some server files that are owned by the server user.  If I try to backup them up using the `tar` command I get:

```
tar: ./somedir Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure due to previous errors
```

However if I do `sudo tar ...` then everything appears to archive file.  Will this change any file ownership / directory ownership / permissions on any of the files being archived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't change, as long as you extract the archive also as superuser.

There are few interesting options. Note the default behavior. From `man tar`:

```
--same-owner
   try extracting files with the same ownership as exists in the ar‐
   chive (default for superuser)

-p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
   extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
```

Additionally you may want to read the answers to [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/463325/693277).